# How to retrieve images stored in Gallery folder of Android device

Tags: android

Hi 
I am writing an Android application in which I want to retrieve the images stored in Gallery folder of Device/emulator. Can any one give me sample code regarding how to achieve this.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have path where your images are stored, use this code to get image as bitmap.

```
FileInputStream in;
BufferedInputStream buf;
try {
        in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/test2.png");
         buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
         Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
         image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
         if (in != null) {
        in.close();
         }
         if (buf != null) {
        buf.close();
         }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
 }
```

You need to iterate through the path: ex

File f=new File("path of dir");

Now get all files using:  f.listFiles();

This is s fair idea..........
Hope it will help........

Answer (score 0):

Just for picking them?. If so, you can use this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
```

Ger